# Delete all Occurrences

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Delete all occurrences Problem 5 (0 / 32)

Define a function deleteAll that has two input argument x and L, where x is an atom and L is a list that contains atomic elements and sublists to any level, and the function returns a list where all occurrences of x are deleted from the list L.

I have problem when list has sublists. I cant go recursively in sublists to check whether it has contains duplicate or not.

```
(defun deleteAll (x L)
    (cond
      ((null L) nil)
      ((not(atom(car L))) (deleteAll x (cdr L)))
      ((not(eq x (car L))) (cons (car L) (deleteAll x (cdr L ))))
      (T(deleteAll x (cdr L)))))
```

Comment: "Problem 5 (0 / 32) "?  Are you asking us to do your homework for you?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor He's pretty close to the solution.

Comment: @Sylwester Sure, but there's a difference between posting the homework problem verbatim and doing some debugging to isolate the issue and ask about it specifically (and I do recognize that "I have problem when list has sublists. I cant go recursively in sublists to check whether it has contains duplicate or not." approaches that).  Even so, copying and pasting a homework assignment without attribution is plagiarism with possible copyright issues.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Wouldn't it be fair use?

Comment: I posted question just to show what's question i did not mean to ask you guys to do homework even it's not homework. My real question was how to get elements of sublists. I dont know why u made it big deal

Comment: It'd probably be fair use if it were attributed (and if there are no other restrictions that the institution imposes (e.g., student code of conduct about class materials, etc.).   As is, it's posted without any attribution, and without even any indication that it's quoted from something else (e.g., a blockquote environment).

Answer (score 0):

In the second term you know from the predicate that you got a list in the first element. You should do the same as the third consequent except you need to process the `car` as well as the `cdr`.